# VBA Open PDFs in a list by selecting cells

Tags: excel, vba, shell, pdf

I am working on a sheet that will allow the users to pull up PDFs based on partial file names in different folders from just clicking on the cell.

My question has two parts.

1. I want the File Path "fp" to grab the active cell value at the top of the column selected. I want to do this for easy of user use down the road in the event the paths change.
2. I have looked up several methods to open a PDF from excel. None of which seem to be working and I am unsure why this is.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Activate Macro by click a cell
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:B10000")) Is Nothing Then
            Call OpenFile
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function OpenAnyFile(strPath As String)
    'Put this in as "ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink OpenMe" was not working. Was trying the shell method.
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.Open (strPath)
End Function

Sub OpenFile()
    Dim fp As String, fn As String, TheFile As String

    fp = "R:\Procurement\Invoices\"
    '(((Item 1))) I want it so that fp will return the top value from the top row of this sheet as i would like the path information to be there for easy user modification.
    fn = ActiveCell.Value

    TheFile = Dir(fp & fn & "*.pdf")

    If CBool(Len(fn)) Then
       MsgBox ("File Found")

       '(((Item 2))) Opening the PDf does not work. Below are two ways i have tried to achieve this.
       Call OpenAnyFile(TheFile)
       'ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink TheFile
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a colleague of my give me a hand with this. Thank you for all the help! Answer is below. Let me know if you see anything that can be improved upon.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:B10000")) Is Nothing Then
            Call OpenFile
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub OpenFile()

Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As Variant

'So that the macro wont try to open nothing
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

'Filepath is at the top of the worksheet above each active cell
filepath = Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value

'File name is just the first portion of the file. the "*" will determine the remaining file name
filename = Dir(filepath & ActiveCell.Value & "*")

'This will open the file below. Needs the filepath and the filenname together although the filepath is inbedded in the filename
If CBool(Len(filename)) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (filepath & filename)

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> - The way you use whitespace is very confusing and makes it hard to understand your program.
> - Your code won't compile as written.
> - Why use a `Function` instead of a `Sub` if you're not returning a value?
> - You'll get an overflow error if a user presses Ctrl A to select the whole worksheet.
> - Read about the shell function  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function

---

Overflow errors can occur when `Target.Count` is used.  Typically this happens with Ctrl + A.  The expanding behavior if Ctrl + A provides very little protection.  At best, you must press it three times to first selecting the region, then the used range, and then the entire worksheet.  At worst, once is needed.

From MS Docs, re: Range object & Count vs CountLarge properties

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.count

> The CountLarge property is functionally the same as the Count property, except that the Count property will generate an overflow error if the specified range has more than 2,147,483,647 cells (one less than 2,048 columns). The CountLarge property, however, can handle ranges up to the maximum size for a worksheet, which is 17,179,869,184 cells.

---

Shell function vs Shell object

The shell function is super easy to use, no need for the overhead that comes with creating an object.

For example, using the shell function to open page 4 of myfile.pdf in Internet Explorer:

```
Shell("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe " + "C:\myfile.pdf#Page=4")
```

Note there is a space after `"[...]iexplore.exe [...]" that is important.

Replace the executable file path with the application of your choice

Note: many applications cannot open a PDF to a specific page.  Simply omit the part `#Page=` segment of it's a problem.

Note: you can also get the PID of the new process like this:

```
vPID = Shell("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe " + "C:\myfile.pdf#Page=4")
```

Comment: Hello @ProfoundlyOblivious,    I didn't realize my white space looked bad, i have now corrected this. Using function instead of sub provides the same results, "Compile error: Variable not defined".

Comment: @Pulsater Yup, *your code will not compile as written*. You're forcing explicit declarations with `Option Explicit` (which is good, you should do this) so **you must declare all your variables or your code will not compile**.  `objShell` is not declared.  You can resolve the error by adding `Dim objShell As Object` before you `Set` it.  ***Re: Sub vs Function*** the only difference between a `Sub` and a `Function`is that a `Function` can return a value.  It isn't a requirement but it is an expectation and anyone reading your code will expect your `Function` to return a value.

Comment: thank you for the explanation between the Sub and Function!  I am very junior at VBA so I appreciate the explanation.    I have changed the function to sub and have put in "Dim objshell As Object" before the set objshell.  The code doesn't seem to do anything and does not appear with any errors.

Comment: @Pulsater In my opinion, you should use the Shell function I linked in my answer. You will probably find it easier to than the Shell object for simple tasks like opening a file. I updated the answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A3:B10000"))
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'Pass the cell value and the value from the top row
            '  of the selected column
            OpenFile rng.Value, Me.Cells(1, rng.Column).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Sub OpenFile(fn As String, fp As String)
    'etc
```

Comment: Hey @Tim Williams,    I get a Compile error when I replace the first portion of the code. I am assuming its because OpenFile on line 8 is not defined. Not sure how you  you change this to work.

Comment: @Pulstar `OpenFile` is declared as a `Sub` and the code provided by  @Tim Williams to update `Worksheet_SelectionChange` should work just fine.  If you're getting a compile error, then my guess is that it's 450 "wrong number if arguments".  Tim subtly changed `OpenFile` so that it accepts 2 arguments.  He provided all the code you need but you probably didn't realize you need to make a change in two different locations.   You'll need to replace the line declaring the `OpenFile` sub with the last line in his code.

Comment: Also note: while this code should work most of the time, an overflow error is possible.  I'll explain that in an update to my answer.